# Linq to Sql convert to generic list in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

I am trying to learn some VB.NET for my coo-op that starts next week, and for that reason i took my portfolio web site that is on C# and just started to converting it to VB.NET to get familiar with the syntax.

I am sure my problem is simple however i have a hard time solving it.
I am trying to grab data with the linq query and then return it as list to bind to the Repeater.

I have the following function:

```
Public Function getProjects() As List(Of portfolio_website)
        Using myPortfolio As New PortfolioDataContext
            Try

                Dim myProjects = (From p In myPortfolio.portfolio_websites _
                                  Order By p.website_id Descending _
                                  Select New With {.name = p.website_name, .id = p.website_id}).Take(5)

                Return myProjects

            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    End Function
```

However I am getting an error.

If i would do it in C# then myProjects will be **var**  and in return i will have

```
return myProjects.ToList();
```

And it would work fine. However if I try to use ToList() in VB.NET i am getting error that it cannot convert it from ling to sql List to the generic list.

How do i do this convertion in VB.NET ? or maybe there is another way ?

I am decent when it comes to C# however somewhat lost with the VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate it.
Second after I asked my question i realized my mystake.
It is same as in C#, but if i take

```
Select New With {.name = p.website_name, .id = p.website_id
```

then i either need to have a custom object, or i need to take everything.
So i changed my linq to sql to the

```
 Dim myProjects = (From p In myPortfolio.portfolio_websites _
                              Order By p.website_id Descending _
                              Select p).Take(5)

 Return myProjects.ToList()
```

and now everything is working.